# Algebraic group preserves product

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-groups, functors

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group over a field $k$, of coordinate ring $O(G)$. This is the same as a functor $F$ from the category of $k$-algebras to the category of groups such that for any $k$-algebra $R$, the group $F(R)$ is in (natural) bijection with the set $Hom_{k\text{-alg.}}(O(G), R)$.

Is it true that for any $k$-algebras $R,S$ we have a group isomorphism
$$G(R \times S) \cong G(R) \times G(S)$$
?

I know that we have a *bjection* $Hom_{k\text{-alg.}}(O(G), R \times S) \simeq Hom_{k\text{-alg.}}(O(G), R) \times Hom_{k\text{-alg.}}(O(G), S)$ but I don't see why it should preserve the group operations.

Comment: Maybe I can use an embedding $G \hookrightarrow GL_n$, and then use the group isomorphism $GL_n(R \times S) \cong GL_n(R) \times GL_n(S)$.

Comment: Yes, this is true more generally for any affine group scheme. The bijection you're thinking of does in fact preserve the group operation. More generally, $G(-)$, regarded as a functor from algebras to groups, preserves limits.

Comment: The key point is that the forgetful functor from groups to sets creates limits (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/created+limit).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : thank you. So if $F : C \to D$ is a functor and $D$ is a concrete category with forgetful functor $U : D \to Set$, and if $U \circ F = Hom(-,c)$ is representable, then $F : C \to D$ preserves limits ? I [agree](https://tlovering.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/representable-functors/) that $U \circ F$ does, but why should also $F$ preserve limits? It uses the fact that $U$ is faithful, I guess.

Comment: Then the answer to this can be helpful : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41472

Comment: I believe this is beginning of the reason why we can identify

$$G(\mathbb A_k) = \prod\limits_v' G(k_v)$$

where $k$ is a global field and $\mathbb A_k$ is the ring of adeles of $k$.

Comment: Let {$R_i$} be a collection of $C$-algebras for a ring $C$, and let $R = \prod_i R_i$. Let X be a C-scheme, and consider the natural map of sets
$X(R) \to \prod_i X(R_i)$. This map is injective when X is quasi-separated (i.e., quasi-compact opens in X have quasi-compact overlap, such as locally noetherian or separated X) and is surjective when X is quasi-compact and the Ri’s are all local.

Comment: (This is [J. Oesterlé, Nombres de Tamagawa et groupes unipotents en caractéristique p, Inventiones Math. 78 (1984), pp. 13–88, Ch. I, Lemme 3.2], except that the quasi-separatedness hypothesis is missing from the statement but is used in the proof.) — taken from _WEIL AND GROTHENDIECK APPROACHES TO ADELIC POINTS_ by BRIAN CONRAD.

Comment: In my above comment, if $U$ reflects limits (e.g. $U : Grp \to Set$ "creates limits"), then $U(F(\mathrm{lim}_i A_i)) = \lim_i U(F(A_i))$ (recall that $F$ is covariant, and $U \circ F = Hom(O(G), -)$). Because $U$ reflects limits, $F(\mathrm{lim}_i A_i)$ is already a limit. If $C=Alg_k, D=Grp$, and limits are just finite products, then $F(R \times S) = F(R) \times F(S)$ as groups. If one takes $C=Sch_k$, one has to consider $\mathrm{colim}_i X_i$ with $X_i = Spec(A_i)$, typically, and $F = Hom(-,G)$ is contravariant...